# Calculating a CRC

Tags: python, crc

I need to be able to calculate a CRC in order to communicate with a machine. I'm pretty new to calculating CRC's so I'm sorry if this exact question has already been answered as I'm not sure what I am looking for. Anyway, I need to compute a CCIT 16-bit CRC in Python. My message is a binary stream that looks like:

```
b'G18M1314D4417,2511165'
```

The message also begins with a STX and ends with a ETX character. I tried using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crc16/0.1.1) Python module:

```
import crc16
print(crc16.crc16xmodem(b'G18M1314D4417,2511165'))
```

Which returned:

```
61154
```

When the correct CRC was:

```
A855
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.3. I got the 'correct' CRC from a message sent from the machine. I'm not sure whether STX/ETX characters should be included as I have never worked with CRC's before.

Comment: What version of python are you using? What (text) encoding are you using? Where did you get the 'correct' CRC from? Should the STX/ETX characters be included in data being CRC'd?

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Comment: FWIW, Serial comms to a piece for kit at my place requires everything but STX & ETX to be included for the checksum.

Comment: I think you'll need to do some more checking that you really need that specific checksum algorithm, and that the `correct` CRC really is for that message - something doesn't add up but I'm afraid it's not possible to see where with this info.

Comment: Could you point me to some sites that would help me to "do some more checking"?

Comment: I found [that site](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) for another questions on CCITT and it has online check for many CRC algorythms. And it agrees with you crc16 XModem is 61154 = 0xEEA2. But none of its list gives A855. Are you sure it is really a CRC, and that there are no other caracters at the beginning or at the end ?

Comment: I'm sure it is a CRC. It's a CCIT 16-bit CRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your machine is using a parametrised CRC algorithm named CRC-16/MCRF4XX.

You can use the [`crcmod`](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/index.html) module which can be installed with `pip`. The CRC can be calculated using the predefined algorithm [crc-16-mcrf4xx](http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.predefined.html#predefined-crc-algorithms). STX and ETX should be included in the CRC calculation.

```
import crcmod
import crcmod.predfined

STX = b'\x02'
ETX = b'\x03'
data = b'G18M1314D4417,2511165'
message = STX + data + ETX

crc16 = crcmod.predefined.Crc('crc-16-mcrf4xx')
crc16.update(message)
crc = crc16.hexdigest()

>>> crc
'A855'
```